# How to bulk extract bitrate data from videos and output them in a text file?

Tags: ffmpeg, grep, cat, mkv

I have several videos in a folder;

```
~/Downloads/movie1.mkv
~/Downloads/movie2.mkv
~/Downloads/movie3.mkv
```

I would like to extract the bitrate for each file, and output the data into a single text file, or output list which I can copy and paste into a text file.

I have installed ffmpeg.
So, for example, the output of `ffmpeg -i movie1.mkv` is;

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.0 + libmatroska v1.1.0
    creation_time   : 2011-04-09T18:18:05.000000Z
  Duration: 00:04:27.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10698 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1038, SAR 1:1 DAR 320:173, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : movie1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : DTS-ES 5.1 @ 1509 Kbps
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Commentary
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip
```

The "bitrate: 10698 kb/s" is the crucial part I am after here.
Let's pretend all three movies have the same bitrate.

I would like to extract the bitrate information from all three videos, and have them output as;

```
movie1.mkv 10698
movie2.mkv 10698
movie3.mkv 10698
```

How would I go about extracting and outputing this information in bulk?

I've been trying a combination of finding by file name, ffmpeg, and then | to grep. e.g ; `find . -name "*.mkv" -exec ffmpeg -i "${1%.mkv}" | grep "bitrate:"`

Current attempts;

1. The command

   ```
   ffmpeg -i movie1.mkv 2>&1 | grep bitrate | sed 's/bitrate: \(.*\), kb/\1/g'
   ```

   returns

   > Duration: 00:04:27.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10698 kb/s
2. The command

   ```
   find . -name "*.mkv" -exec ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "${~/Downloads/1%.mkv}"  ';`'
   ```

   returns

   > ~/Downloads/1%.mkv: No such file or directory
   >   ~/Downloads/1%.mkv: No such file or directory
   >   ~/Downloads/1%.mkv: No such file or directory

I feel that I'm close here, and that there's just something wrong with the find and recalling the output of find into ffprobe.

Comment: `ls *.mp4 | xargs -i{} ffprobe -i {} -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of csv=s=x:p=0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To screen:**

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} sh -c " echo -n '{} ' && ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p' "
```

**To file result.txt:**

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} sh -c " echo -n '{} ' && ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p' " > result.txt
```

You will see in file result.txt:

```
somefile1.mkv 1788 kb/s
somefile2.mkv 1681 kb/s
...
```

**Formatted output example:**

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} sh -c " echo -n 'Filename: {}, Bitrate is: ' && ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p' " > result.txt
```

You will see in file result.txt:

```
Filename: somefile1.mkv, Bitrate is: 1788 kb/s
Filename: somefile2.mkv, Bitrate is: 1681 kb/s
...
```

Comment: I keep getting the "missing argument to `-exec " error

Comment: Try: `find . -name "*.mkv" -exec ffmpeg -i "${1%.mkv}" | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p'`

What output you get?

Comment: Still getting the "missing argument to `-exec " error. I have found that : ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "movie1.mkv"   returns just the bit rate, so if somehow  the output of find, and the use echo can be used with that, it might do the trick

Comment: I added the ';', and it returned with a "No such file or directory error three times, so I think there's an issue in the finding of the file name, and passing it to ffmpeg.

Comment: I found errors and edited my answer with some new examples

Comment: Your latest edit (i.e To screen/To file Result/Formatted output example) worked perfectly. Thank You so much.

Comment: Stangely, while your code works perfectly for files in ~/Downloads, it returns a syntax error when done in folders of mounted drives ;  "sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"  EDIT: no, it works now. Thanks Again.

Comment: Just try run `ffmpeg -i somefile.mkv` on mounted drive; Syntax error: "(" - looks like for filenames containing spaces

Comment: Yes, some of the videos have the year in the filename such as "Bday party (2015)", which causes a syntax error

Comment: Try this: `find . -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} sh -c " echo -n '{} ' && ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p' "`

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. You might want to edit your above answer and include this command for future people, as its hidden in these below comments. Much appreciated, you've helped me out a lot.